# How come this matrix with non-degenerate eigenvalues has two sets of possible eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I expect that when we have a $n \times n$ matrix with non-degenerate eigenvalues, that is to say a matrix for which none of its $n$ eigenvalues have the same value, that there is a unique set of n normalized eigenvectors.

However for this matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

With eigenvalues {$\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$,$\lambda_3$} = {1, i, -i} its unnormalized eigenvectors can be:

$x_1$ = $(1,0,0)$, $x_2$ = $(0,i,1)$, $x_3$ = $(0,-i,1)$

Or

$x_1$ = $(1,0,0)$, $x_2$ = $(0,1,-i)$, $x_3$ = $(0,1,i)$

How come we're able to find two different sets of eignvectors?

Comment: If the unit norm eigen-vector $x$ works then $-x$ works in the real case. So there is no reason to have unique eigen-vector even if they have unit norm. If you allow complex numbers, then the coefficient can be any complex number from the unit circle, like $-i$ or $i$ in your examples. Your expectations are just wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that in the case of complex normalized eigenvalues the vector components for the same eigenvalue can differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen-vectors are never unique even if they are normalised, because you can multiply them by a scalar. If you allow complex numbers, then the scalar can be any complex number from the unit circle, like − or  and retain their normalization.

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvectors are never unique. In your case, all you can say is that each eigenspace is one-dimensional. Can you find the respective scalars that relate the two elements of each eigenspace that you found?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, indeed they differ by a factor of i. Lelouch answered the question but did so as a comment, I'll see if I can mark it as answered while pointing to their response.

Comment: Dear George, I did not comment, I answered. In general on this site answering questions in the comments is discouraged, but quite common.

Comment: Indeed but it was not the answer that resolved my question. Lelouch answered the question but did so as a comment, I have reworded it and posted my own answer. Hopefully that follows the forum rules. :) Edit: it won't let me mark my own answer as correct...